# Javascript play sound in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio

this is my code. It works fine in Chrome but in Firefox not, although I added an .ogg Version.

```
    if(new_id != old_id)
            {
                var audio = new Audio();
                if(audio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") == "probably") {
                    playSound("signal.mp3");
                } else if(audio.canPlayType("audio/ogg") == "probably") {
                    playSound("signal.ogg");
            }
```

Comment: Check if Firefox is muted. And Also maybe you have to: Right-click on your sound/speakers icon in the system tray and select Playback Devices, go to Speakers properties (the one which is green-ticked, also disable the red ones, if any), then go to Enhancements and tick Disable all sound effects. And that's it, restart the browser and enjoy.

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools if the file is being loaded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox can't play mp3 and some ogg files check here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp

http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

I think your problem is that Firefox dosen't suport the audio/ogg codec.

Try using **WAV** insted of ogg and mp3.